# How to retry failed test that use Jest and Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm writting the automation test that uses Jest and Typescript. I followed this documentation to retry the failed test but it didn't work. I guess because it just applies to Javascriot, but if I use Typescriot, is there anything that I could make it worked?

https://github.com/bluzi/jest-retries

Comment: Why does it not work? Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [jest.retryTimes](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestretrytimes) API, which is available since Jest v25 (2019):

```js
jest.retryTimes(1);
let j = 0;
describe("Flaky", () => {
  it("should pass only on second run", async () => {
    expect(j++).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Note, this option can't work globally, you need to insert it per file/spec.

Comment: URL in Jest v29 - https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestretrytimesnumretries-options

Comment: just to note, as of 2024 and if you include this in a pre-run script pointed to in `setupFiles` within a jest config, you can indeed get it to work globally.  I used this exact test.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on the answer from dhilt, you can set it globally via a setup file.

I'm not sure if this is a recent change.

```json
// jest.config.json
{
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.tsx"],
  
  ...

}
```

```js
// jest.setup.tsx

... 

jest.retryTimes(5, { logErrorsBeforeRetry: true });

... // any other pre/post test logic
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestretrytimesnumretries-options